# WARNING: supervisor_manager: The process crashed some time after starting successfully. Fail to allocate bitmap

Tags: webots

I am trying to navigate a drone moves towards target(car) using PPO algo. after 1320 episodes, I got this message:

```
      WARNING: supervisor_manager: The process crashed some time after starting successfully.
Fail to allocate bitmap
```

in the supervisor controller, after every episode the initial position of both target and drone changes.

```py
def reset(self):
        """
        Used to reset the world to an initial state.
        Default, problem-agnostic, implementation of reset method,
        using Webots-provided methods.
        *Note that this works properly only with Webots versions >R2020b
        and must be overridden with a custom reset method when using
        """
        
        self.simulationReset()
        self.simulationResetPhysics()
        # super.reset()
        super(Supervisor,self).step(int(self.getBasicTimeStep()))
        # Getting Car Node
        quadrant_map = {0: [7, 7], 1: [-7, 7], 2: [-7, -7], 3: [7, -7]}
        car=self.getFromDef('bmw')
        # Getting the Tranlation Field
        car_translation =car.getField('translation')
        
        # print(f'[********************car spawning in episode {self.episodeCount}]')
        # print("self.target_quadrant=",self.target_quadrant)
        
        # if self.target_quadrant % 1 == 0:
        # if self.episodeCount % 1 == 0:
        # print(f'[car spawning in quadrant {self.target_quadrant}]')
        self.x, self.y = quadrant_map[self.target_quadrant]
        self.target_quadrant = (self.target_quadrant + 1) % 4
        
        # #Translation Function   for car
        vector= [self.x,self.y,self.z]
        car_translation.setSFVec3f(vector)  # this actually changes position defined
      
      
        ###################################
        ####### Drone Rotation Code #######
        ###################################
        
        drone = self.getFromDef('Drone')
        drone_rotation = drone.getField('rotation')
        x, y, z, angle = drone_rotation.getSFRotation()
        self.angle = angle if self.angle is None else self.angle
        self.angle = np.degrees(self.angle)
        # print(self.angle)
        self.angle = self.angle + 45
        self.angle = self.angle - 360 if self.angle > 180 else self.angle
        self.angle = self.angle + 360 if self.angle < -180 else self.angle
        # print(self.angle)
        self.angle = float(np.radians(self.angle))

        vector = [x, y, z, self.angle]
        # print(vector)
        drone_rotation.setSFRotation(vector)

        return self.get_default_observation()
```